How to add cdkDragHandle to dynamically generated element?
In an angular app using angular-cdk, I have a draggable container. Into the container elements are added dynamically. The container has cdkDrag directive, and one of the dynamically generated children should be the drag handle.
<div class="container" cdkDrag>
    // generated elements come here
<div>

How do I make the generated element the drag handle?

please share the minmal reproducible code, if possible a stackblitz with the issue happening

@NarenMurali there is no issue happening, as there is no proposed solution for the problem.

I want to see how you are dynamically generating, a working example is best for checking based on the code you have

@NarenMurali I am loading some micro-frontends built with webpack federated engine. Not really something I can easily share with stackblitz.
